# Send a File From Api Server to NodeJs to Browser

Tags: node.js

I have an API Server and NodeJs Server and when a file is requested NodeJs redirected the request to API Server

API Server Send the File as raw data to NodeJs
and Nodejs redirects the file to the browser

But when I checked the network data using wire shark the packet received at browser is not original as that from API Server (work in case of text files, but not in image, video, pdf, doc etc)

```
router.get('/GetCaseSupportDocument', function (req, res) {

    var MyJsonData = {
         DocId:parseInt(req.query.DocId) || 0
    };

    request({
        url: 'http://somedomain/someurl', //URL to hit
        method: 'POST',
        json: MyJsonData

    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
              res.status(200).send('Failed');
        } else {
              res.status(200).send(body);
            }
    })

});
```

Can anyone tell why it changes between NodeJs to Browser?
Is there any better solution for this type of transmission?

Updated After finding solution . This works

```
    router.get('/GetCaseSupportDocument', function (req, res) {

        var MyJsonData = {
           DocId:parseInt(req.query.DocId) || 0

        };

        request({
            url: Url.CaseService + 'GetCaseSupportDocument', //URL to hit
            method: 'POST',
            json: MyJsonData
        }).pipe(res);

})
```

Comment: Just a minor comment: If you encounter an error you probably shouldn't return a status of 200. If you can isolate the type of error more clearly, you can figure out exactly what it should be, but I'd just return a 500 in the meantime.

Comment: @HomerPlata . i just want to hide to external world the existence of an API server  in the application.. Dats y returned "failed".  anyway thanks ... 

Like i said i get the response . but its altered someway after some characters in beginning and works well in case of text files

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple proxy using streams that you can try:

```
router.get('/GetCaseSupportDocument', function (req, res) {
  var MyJsonData = {
    DocId: parseInt(req.query.DocId) || 0
  };

 // updated the response
 request({
    url: 'http://somedomain/someurl', //URL to hit
    method: 'POST',
    json: MyJsonData
  }).pipe(res);

});
```

More details with proxy-ing you can find on the `request` documentation https://github.com/request/request

Comment: tried that way bt i gets this error ----  stream.js:74
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^
Error: write after end
    at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:439:15)

Comment: req.pipe at beginning was not needed..nw it works ... edited my question with answer